# jQuery change active state of multiple elements on page when different categories are selected

Tags: jquery

jQuery rookie here and first question on stackexchange – please go easy.

I have a page with a tabbed menu (5 in-page nav tabs / “feature categories”) and a long list of ~28 “features”. Each of the feature categories (tabs) has approximately 5-6 corresponding features.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page_features_overview">

    <div class="container public_content_container">

        <div class="tabbed_content">

            <div class="col span_2">

                <div class="tabs_container">
                            <div class="tab feature_category_1 selected">Feature Category 1<div class="indicator"></div></div>
                            <div class="tab feature_category_2">Feature Category 2<div class="indicator"></div></div> <!-- etc. -->
                            <div class="tab feature_category_3">Feature Category 3<div class="indicator"></div></div>
                            <div class="tab feature_category_4">Feature Category 4<div class="indicator"></div></div>
                    <div class=“tab feature_category_5”>Feature Category 5<div class="indicator"></div></div>
                </div> <!-- CLOSE .tabs_container -->

            </div>

            <div class="col span_10">

                <div class="features_grid">

                    <div class="feature_box feature_category_1 highlighted">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-search zmdi-hc-3x feature_overview_icon"></i>
                        <div class="feature_title">
                            Feature title text here
                        </div>
                        <div class="feature_description">
                            Feature description text here.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feature_box feature_category_4 highlighted">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-settings zmdi-hc-3x feature_overview_icon"></i>
                        <div class="feature_title">
                            Feature title text here
                        </div>
                        <div class="feature_description">
                            Feature description text here.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        … etc.
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- CLOSE .features_grid -->

            </div> <!-- CLOSE .col .span_10 -->

        </div> <!-- CLOSE .tabbed_content -->

    </div> <!-- CLOSE .container .public_content_container -->

</div> <!-- CLOSE .page_features_overview -->
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is to get the features to be highlighted when a corresponding category tab is selected. I understand that this can be done by changing the active state of the features upon selection of each tab, but I am not sure how to go about it.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
      $('.tabbed_content .tabs_container .tab').click(function(evt) {
        var selectedTab = $(this);
        var featureGroup = selectedTab.parents('.tabbed_content');
        var allTabs = featureGroup.find('.tab');
        var allContent = featureGroup.find('.feature_box');

        // clear selections
        allTabs.removeClass('selected');
        selectedTab.addClass('selected');
        allContent.addClass('hidden');

        // find correlated content
        var idx = selectedTab.index();
        var selectedContent = $(allContent);
        selectedContent.removeClass('hidden');

        });
    });

</script>
```

This code works fine for the tabs menu (i.e. it allows me to select and de-select the individual feature category tabs and to change their state to active / ‘selected’). However, what I am struggling with is how to tie the selection of individual category tabs to the corresponding features so they are highlighted.

Sorry if this is a really dumb question but I am lost. I will try to clarify if any of the above is not clear. Thank you!

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle? It's hard to understand. Take a look at this in a minute: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Hi @MarcosPérezGude, thanks for your comment! I have tried to put together a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/32k_/c0ee2y6c/2/

Comment: I update your fiddle because I've included jquery library to work. Test your fiddle before you share with us. https://jsfiddle.net/c0ee2y6c/3/

Comment: @MarcosPerezGude, brilliant! Thanks so much for your help, it works perfectly. Learned something new today. Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome :) Accept the answer as correct as well upvote it ;) . See you soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem I update your fiddle. I add an attribute in the menu links `rel` that identifies what box we need to activate. Then I hide all content boxes and then I show only the content box that I need:

https://jsfiddle.net/c0ee2y6c/5/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tabbed_content .tabs_container .tab').click(function(evt) {
    var selectedTab = $(this);
    var featureGroup = selectedTab.parents('.tabbed_content');
    var allTabs = featureGroup.find('.tab');
    var allContent = featureGroup.find('.feature_box');
    // get the rel attribute to know what box we need to activate
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    
    // clear selections
    allTabs.removeClass('selected');
    selectedTab.addClass('selected');
    
    // hide all boxes
    $('.feature_box').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    //show what we need
    $('.feature_box.feature_category_'+rel).show();

    // find correlated content
    var idx = selectedTab.index();
    var selectedContent = $(allContent);
    selectedContent.removeClass('hidden');

  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:block;
  color: blue;
}

/* Features Overview page – CATEGORY TABS */

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .tabs_container {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  float: left;
  margin:45px 0px
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .tabs_container .tab {
  float:none;
  width:100%;
  color:#1193f6;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 24px;
  line-height:40px;
  height:40px;
  font-size:12px;
  border-left:1px solid #efefef;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:500;
  overflow:hidden;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .tabs_container .tab .indicator {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:none;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .tabs_container .tab:hover .indicator {
  display:block;
  border-left:4px solid blue
}


.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .tabs_container .tab.selected .indicator {
  display:block;
  border-left:4px solid red
}


/* Features Overview page – FEATURES GRID */

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .features_grid {
  background:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .features_grid .feature_box {

  background:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:12px;
  padding:12px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .features_grid .feature_box .selected {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .features_grid .feature_box.selected .indicator {
  display:block;
  background-color: red;
  border:4px solid #1193f6
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .features_grid .feature_box .feature_title {
  color:#363636;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:500;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: default;
}

.page_features_overview .tabbed_content .features_grid .feature_box .feature_description {
  color:#888;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:18px;
  margin-top:6px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:400;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page_features_overview">

  <div class="container public_content_container">

    <div class="tabbed_content">

      <div class="col span_2">

        <div class="tabs_container">

          <div class="tab feature_category_1 selected" rel="1">Feature Category 1<div class="indicator"></div></div>
          <div class="tab feature_category_2" rel="2">Feature Category 2<div class="indicator"></div></div>
          <div class="tab feature_category_3" rel="3">Feature Category 3<div class="indicator"></div></div>
          <div class="tab feature_category_4" rel="4">Feature Category 4<div class="indicator"></div></div>
          <div class="tab feature_category_5" rel="5">Feature Category 5<div class="indicator"></div></div>

        </div> <!-- CLOSE .tabs_container -->

      </div>

      <div class="col span_10">

        <div class="features_grid">

          <div class="feature_box feature_category_1">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-search zmdi-hc-3x feature_overview_icon"></i>
            <div class="feature_title">
              Feature title text here
            </div>
            <div class="feature_description">
              Feature description text here.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="feature_box feature_category_4 hidden">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-settings zmdi-hc-3x feature_overview_icon"></i>
            <div class="feature_title">
              Feature title text here
            </div>
            <div class="feature_description">
              Feature description text here.
            </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- CLOSE .features_grid -->

      </div> <!-- CLOSE .col .span_10 -->

    </div> <!-- CLOSE .tabbed_content -->

  </div> <!-- CLOSE .container .public_content_container -->

</div> <!-- CLOSE .page_features_overview -->
```